# How does Furion's ult bounce?

Tags: dota-2

It seems like whenever I will be farming and minding my own business, an enemy Furion's ult will come out of nowhere and hit me on the last bounce, taking a large chunk of my health.

When I play Furion, I know that I can cast it globally on any creep that I have vision of. Does it use this same idea to determine how it bounces across the map? That is, will it only hit enemy heroes/creeps if you have vision of them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nature's Prophet's ultimate begins bouncing with the nearest visible non-allied unit (it also hits neutrals) to where you targeted. It then bounces to the closest such unit and repeats until there are either no more un-hit units or no more bounces.

Obviously, the later bounces deal extra damage and so you want to manipulate the ultimate so that whatever hero you're trying to gank or lane you're trying to push takes as late of a bounce as possible. This is actually hard to intuitively do: when a teamfight starts that you're in the middle of you're almost always better off casting the ultimate far away from you using the minimap.

Comment: small addition: if something comes in to visibility that wasn't in visibility when the ultimate was bouncing, it is now possible to hit (instead of the ultimate only targeting things that were visible at the time of cast).